# Преобразование массива в строку

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу додуматься, мой контроллер:

```
    $userids = DB::select("SELECT id FROM users");
    $userid_array = array();
    foreach($userids as $userid){
        $userid_array[] = (array)$userid;
    }
    foreach($userid_array as $users){
        $test = $users;
        $profile = DB::table('web-application.search_profiles')
                            ->whereRaw("user_id = " . $users)
                            ->get();
    }
```

Моя ошибка

> Array to string conversion

Comment: нв какую строку и в каком файле ссылается ошибка?

Comment: Вы какие-то страшные вещи пытаетесь выполнить `DB::select`, `whereRaw`. Необходимо подробнее описать, что вы хотите получить этими запросами, какие входящие данные.

Comment: @РустамГимранов ругается на эту фигню ->whereRaw("user_id = " . $users)

Comment: Тем более, что модель *User* изначально во фреймворке описана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel уже написал вам подсказку — в конкатенацию был подставлен массив ("user_id = " . $users)

Все потому, что приведение объекта к массиву отдаст вам массив. Ваш `$userid_array` — это массив массивов, а не массив чисел.

Вместо  `$userid_array[] = (array)$userid;` можно попробовать написать `$userid_array[] = $userid->id;`